# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un select de registros que no coincidan entre dos fechas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener las habitaciones que no estén en reserva actualmente, es decir, que la fecha actual **no** esté entre la fechaInicio ni la fechaFin.

Tengo este select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM habitaciones 
WHERE idHotel=3 and idHabitacion <> (
     SELECT [idHabitacion] 
     FROM [dbo].[reservas] 
     WHERE idHotelReserva=3 and fechaInicio<GETDATE() and fechaFin>GETDATE()
)
```

Pero **me salta error** porque la subconsulta devuelve varios resultados:

> *La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza
> como expresión.*

Trabajo con SQLSERVER.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes asignar un <> a una subconsulta, para esto puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
Select *
       From habitaciones
       Where idhotel = 3 And idhabitacion Not In (
                                                   Select idhabitacion
                                                          From dbo.reservas
                                                          Where idhotelreserva = 3 And fechainicio < GetDate() And fechafin > GetDate()
                                                 );
```

O también podrías utilizar un Not Exists

```
 SELECT * FROM habitaciones WHERE idHotel=3
  and Not Exists
    (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[reservas] r 
        WHERE r.idHotelReserva=3 and r.fechaInicio<GETDATE() and r.fechaFin>GETDATE()
    And r.idHabitacion = habitaciones.id
    );
```

Donde el conjunto del Not Exists `r`, se relaciona con el conjunto externo `Habitaciones`

[In Tsql](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Exists Tsql](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Muchas gracias Javi! las dos alternativas devuelven los resultados correctos.